# "invalid login" in Android studio fabric plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

I've installed fabric plugin version 2.3.1 for Android studio 2.2.1 but i cannot login into it, I've installed it on previous versions of Android studio and it was working. I appreciate it if you help me with that, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under vpn connection in our company and the fabric didn't recognize it, so I used L2TP/IPSec virtual networking and it solved my problem